# Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

Tags: web-hosting, ftp

Hai guys,

When i used filezilla to host my web page which was moved to a new server i got this error

`Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known".`

I ve checked my hostname,username and password all was fine, but i dont know what is going wrong please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks like it can't resolve the hostname you've entered.  Try resolving it in a command line, see what happens.